# Error in tm_map method

Tags: r, classification, tm, corpus

I am new in R as well as `tm` package. My taks is to perform text document classification using decision trees. I am following someone's [project.](http://jbusta.cz/files/classification.pdf) At the page no 14 there is a full code. There are 2 types of documents, which I have loaded using `DirSource` without any problems. My next step was merging these 2 corpuses into collection

```
   # Merge corpora into one collection 
docs <- c( wheat.train , crude.train , wheat.test , crude.test ) ;
```

And then I would like to make some pre-processing.

```
#pre-processing
docs.p <- docs
docs.p <- tm_map (docs.p, stripWhitespace)
```

But I got such error

```
    Error in UseMethod("tm_map", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'tm_map' applied to an object of class "list"
```

I understand that this guy is using one of the `tm's` previous version, and currently `tm_map` takes as an argument a corpus, not a collection of corpuses. My question is how to create such collection of corpuses that it will be possible to perform pre-processing on it?

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me using `list` instead of `c` and than `lapply`.

```
ex1 <- "bla bla blah   "
ex2 <- "dunno    what else to say    "

wheat <- Corpus(VectorSource(ex1))
crude <- Corpus(VectorSource(ex2))

docs <- list(wheat, crude)
docs.p <- lapply(docs, tm_map, stripWhitespace)
```

Comment: It worked for me too :) I have followed your suggestions and nextly:

`dtm.mx <- lapply(docs.p, DocumentTermMatrix, control = list ( weighting = weightTf ) ); `
and it worked, but I as have noticed `length(docs)` using `list` equals 4, but using `c` it equals 12. Can u tell me what is a difference? Following provided source code, after using `list` as you suggested I have encounted another problem. `dtm <- as.data.frame ( inspect (dtm.mx) )` returns `Error in UseMethod("inspect", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'inspect' applied to an object of class "list"`

Comment: I guess you are in love with R, so I would appreciate your help very much :)

Comment: `length(docs)` in my example returns 2, as expected, not sure where your results come from. You'll need to provide a reproducible example. I'm not sure how `dtm` is supposed to look like, if you give concrete guidance I might be able to help. `dtm <- as.data.frame(lapply(dtm.mx, inspect))` doesn't through an error, but again, I don't know if the result is what you're looking for.